# Openvpn - Terminal blocked after starting connection

Tags: command-line, bash, vpn, ftp, openvpn

i have a little Problem with openvpn. I want to establish a VPN connect with open vpn, then get a file from an FTP Server and than close the connection.

The VPN and the FTP are working fine. But if i start the VPN Connection with:

```
sudo /etc/openvpn/openvpn client1.ovpn
```

Terminal stops at:

```
Tue Apr 26 13:54:08 2016 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.9
Tue Apr 26 13:54:08 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

So the Tunnel is working fine. But the Terminal is blocked and i cant connect the FTP in the same Terminal.

Finally i want to do something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "ich logge mich jetzt beim VPN ein "

sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/magicbox1.ovpn

echo "bin eingeloggt, hole jetzt die Daten" 

sudo ncftpget -DD -T -R -v -u <username> -p <passwort>  \10.8.0.1 /home/  /*

echo "Fertig, schließe jetzt den VPN"

sudo killall openvpn
```

i also tried with nohup within the openvpn start. So i dont get any information about openvpn inm the Terminal but its also blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use killall at the end of your script you can detach your openvpn task from the terminal by adding a `&`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "ich logge mich jetzt beim VPN ein "
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/magicbox1.ovpn &

echo "warte auf den server"
sleep 5

echo "bin eingeloggt, hole jetzt die Daten" 
sudo ncftpget -DD -T -R -v -u <username> -p <passwort>  \10.8.0.1 /home/  /*

echo "Fertig, schließe jetzt den VPN"
sudo killall openvpn
```

Comment: hmm..better than before.. but i still need an "enter" to get the prompt back after starting sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/magicbox1.ovpn & and when i start the script i still have the output in the terminal and the script is not waiting till the vpn connection is established before doing the next job

Comment: @Chrisko Try `sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/magicbox1.ovpn & disown && echo "bin eingeloggt, hole jetzt die Daten"` this will only do the folowing commands if he before one not fails.

Comment: same than before... "[1] 4586
bin eingeloggt, hole jetzt die Daten ......Tue Apr 26 14:28:34 2016 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.9
Tue Apr 26 14:28:34 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed"... and again no prompt and the echo is before vpn is established

Comment: @Chrisko ok my revised answer should fix all your problems

Comment: great.. works.. but i have:  getfile.sh: disown: not found

Comment: Then leave that command out.

Comment: is there a better way than wait with sleep till the vpn connection is established? Something like wait till process is ready...